# Prioritize JavaScript array according to key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Javascript array

```
var airports = [
{
    iata: "CPT",
    city: "Cape Town",
    airport: "Cape Town International",
    country: "South Africa",
    priority: 9
},

{
    iata: "HLA",
    city: "Johannesburg",
    airport: "Lanseria",
    country: "South Africa",
    priority: 1
},

{
    iata: "JNB",
    city: "Johannesburg",
    airport: "OR Tambo International",
    country: "South Africa",
    priority: 9
},
];
```

**TAKE NOTE:** The final .js file has over 3 000 airports listed.

I'm trying to get Autocomplete to return prioritized results.

In the example above, if a user starts typing "Johannesburg" it must prioritize according to the "priority" value e.g. JNB, OR Tambo International should always show above HLA, Lanseria.

Currently Autocomplete display results according to where it is listed in the array.

A fiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cgaybba/17p7uyvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code maybe useful for you

```
var airportArray = [
    {
        iata: "CPT",
        city: "Cape Town",
        airport: "Cape Town International",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 9
    },

    {
        iata: "HLA",
        city: "Johannesburg",
        airport: "Lanseria",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 1
    },

    {
        iata: "JNB",
        city: "Johannesburg",
        airport: "OR Tambo International",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 9
    },

    {
        iata: "DUR",
        city: "Durban",
        airport: "King Shaka International",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 9
    },

    {
        iata: "BFN",
        city: "Bloemfontein",
        airport: "Bram Fischer International",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 9
    },

    {
        iata: "PLZ",
        city: "Port Elizabeth",
        airport: "Port Elizabeth Airport",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 8
    },

    {
        iata: "AGZ",
        city: "Aggeneys",
        airport: "Aggeneys Airport",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 6
    },

    {
        iata: "GRJ",
        city: "George",
        airport: "George Airport",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 7
    },

    {
        iata: "ELS",
        city: "East London",
        airport: "Ben Schoeman Airport",
        country: "South Africa",
        priority: 7
    }

];
 var airportArray = airportArray.sort(function(a, b) {                  
                return (b.priority || 0) - (a.priority || 0);
            });   
$(function() {

    function custom_source(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response($.grep(airportArray, function(value) {
            return matcher.test(value.label) || matcher.test(value.value) || matcher.test(value.airport) || matcher.test(value.country);
        }));
    }

    $("#input_1_1").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: custom_source,
        ookupLimit: 3,
        clearCache: true,
        sortBeforeLimit: function(suggestions) {
            var sorted = suggestions.sort(function(a, b) {
                    alert(a.priority);
                return (a.priority || 0) - (b.priority || 0);
            });
            return sorted;
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            // Text inside INPUT while selecting airport
            $("#input_1_1").val(ui.item.city + ', ' + ui.item.airport + ' (' + ui.item.iata + '), ' + ui.item.country);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // Text inside INPUT AFTER selecting
            $("#input_1_1").val(ui.item.city + ' (' + ui.item.iata + ')');
            $("#input_1_2").val(ui.item.iata);
            return false;
        }
    })

        .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li>')
            .append('<div class="result-row">' + item.city + ', ' + item.airport + ' (' + item.iata + '), ' + item.country + '</div>')
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: Your solutions seems to be working. Will see when I'm using it with a larger array

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the results of `$.grep` with a custom comparison function:

```
let temp = $.grep(airportArray, function(value)  
    return matcher.test(value.label) || matcher.test(value.value) || matcher.test(value.airport) || matcher.test(value.country);
}

response(temp.sort((airportA, airportB) => {
    if(airportA.priority < airportB.priority){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(airportA.priority > airportB.priority){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}));
```